# Arrangement of musicians into distinct bands - combinatorics solution?

Tags: combinatorics

Real life problem.

I have 8 different musical instruments and 14 players of each instrument. There will be 9 sessions where the players are placed into 14 bands (each band has 1 of each instrument). So if each instrumentalist was labeled 1-14 for their respective instrument, the first session could be band 1: all instrument 1s, band 2 all instrument 2s etc.

Is it possible for each band in each session to be unique? I.e. Trumpet 1 doesn't play with clarinet 1 more than once (and doesn't play with any other instrumental person from other instruments more than once). I am able to brute force this with 3 or 4 sessions but past that it gets difficult.

While I have a math degree and took some combinatorics classes, I am definitely not an expert. I think this might fall under [Combinatorial Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design) but  I am not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set this up and solve as an integer program. If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, it could be something like the following. (Then this could be solved using a variety of optimization software. E.g., SCIP in python)

Sets:

$S$ Set of sessions

$B$ Set of bands in each session

$P$ Set of people

$I$ Set of instruments

Parameters:

$c_{pi} \in \{0,1\}$ if person $p$ plays instrument $i$, $0$ otherwise

Variables:

$X_{psb} \in \{0,1\}$ if person $p$ plays in band $b$ in session $s$

$Y_{pp'sb} \in \{0,1\}$ if person $p$ plays with person $p'$ in band $b$ in session $s$

Formulation:

min $0$

subject to:

$ \sum_{p \in P} c_{pi}X_{psb} = 1, \forall s \in S, b\in B, i \in I$

$ Y_{pp'sb} \geq X_{psb} + X_{p'sb} - 1, \forall p \in P, p' \in P \setminus \{p\}, s \in S, b\in B$

$ \sum_{s\in S}\sum_{b \in B} Y_{pp'sb} \leq 1, \forall p \in P, p' \in P \setminus \{p\},$

I believe you're looking for any feasible solution that satisfies your constraints - so the objective doesn't matter. The first constraint set requires there to be exactly 1 instrument of each type in each band. The second constraint set assigns an indicator variable if a person has been assigned to the same band as another person in the same session. The third constraint set only allows you to assign 2 people to the same band once.

Comment: Re-reading the original question - are you trying to make assignments or are you wondering if it is possible or not? If It's the former, an optimization approach will work for you. If the latter - you could use an optimization approach (if there's a feasible solution it means it's possible; infeasible means it's not), though there may be alternate ways to check that than setting up a model.

Comment: I am trying to actually make the assignments. At the end of the day, if you pick any player, say Trumpet 12, he/she shouldn't be matched with the same player from any other instrument more than once in all 9 sessions.

Comment: Great - I think an integer program such as above will work for you. If you have trouble implementing, let me know.

Comment: I've been thinking about this some more - if you adjusted the variable $Y_{pp'sb}$ to be $Y_{pp's}$ instead, the program would be substantially smaller. Constraint set 2 would stay the same, and for constraint set 3, you would remove the summation over $B$. Also I'm not sure how computational you are, but an easier(?) option than Python might be Open Solver (https://opensolver.org/) for Excel. It's an add-in that allows you to solve moderate size integer programs. Solver Studio - another Excel add-in (https://solverstudio.org/) can handle larger ones.

Comment: I am not familiar with any of the computational programs unfortunately. I downloaded scip today and played around with it but couldn’t figure out how to do much. I do appreciate you help this far though.